# compare and subtract current value from next 3 value

Tags: python, perl

Given array of values, for example **1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9**, and the current value is **7**, I want to see result of **7-4, 8-7, 8-7, 9-7, 9-7**.

The pseudo code is below. I tried but i am stuck:

```
sub func
{ 
    my @arr = (1,3,4,7,8,8,9,9);
    my @arr1;
    foreach my $i (0..$#arr) 
    {        
        push (@arr1,$arr[$i]);
        if ($current_value =~ 7) 
        {  
            my $brk= (scalar @arr1) -1;
            for (my $counter = (scalar @arr1); $counter >= $brk ;$counter--) 
            {                        
                if($arr1[$counter] < $current_value)
                {
                    print $current_value - $arr1[$counter];
                }
                else
                {
                    next;
                }
            }          
        }
        else
        {
            next;        
        }    
    }  
}
```

Comment: I compared current value and previous value. my next task is want to compare current value with next three value.

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm you are aiming for. Please elaborate on that so we can help you find a solution.

Comment: I am newbie to perl let me guide anybody

Comment: so given a different array of values, like 1,3,4,7,8,8,9,9 and the current value is 7, then you'll want to see 7-4, 8-7, 8-7, 9-7, 9-7?

Comment: yes, thats the logic.

Comment: So share your script or pseudo-code, and we'll go over it. Sound pretty simple to me.

Comment: ok wait.. i ll share my code with you.

Comment: sub func
{ 
  my @arr = (1,3,4,7,8,8,9,9);
  my@arr1;
  foreach my $i (0..$#arr) 
  {        
    push (@arr1,$arr[$i]);
    if ($current_value =~ 7) 
      {  
          my $brk= (scalar @arr1) -1;
         for (my $counter = (scalar @arr1); $counter >= $brk ;$counter--) 
          {                        
            if($arr1[$counter] < $current_value)
            {
                print $current_value - $arr1[$counter];
            }
          else
          {
            next;
          }
        }          
      }
      else
      {
        next;        
      }    
  }  
}

Comment: This is my sudo code i have done subtraction of previous value from current value, I want to see i.e. 8-7,8-7,9-7 etc.

Comment: I'll go over it when I have some time. Please edit the main post with the algorithm you wrote here in the comments.

Comment: I ll post algorithm.. thank you.

Comment: I'd split the problem to several steps: (1) Find the value index. If given an index you can skip this step. (2) Compute the subtraction with the value or values below it. (3) Compute the subtraction with the value or values above it.

Comment: yup I know. And Be sure with out any dependency of perl package. we have to develope this logic

Comment: It's as simple as it gets, no dependencies needed. First step: find the index, You can write a simple `for` loop for that, or just provide the index. Second step: compute the subtraction value with the value at the previous index: `print $value - $arr[$index-1]`. Third step: loop from `$index + 1` (let's call it `$i`) to the end of the array and in each step do `print  $arr[$i] - $value`

Comment: ok i ll do it. and if i want to compute substraction above value(s) that must be same ,i.e. 8-7,8-7,8-7 how can i do it?

Comment: again, you don't care about the values. only about the indices.

Comment: ohk.. cool... got it.. thank you..

Comment: you're welcome. please vote the comment or comments that helped you  most.

Comment: I copied the main comment I thought was the best answer to an answer post, so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the problem to several steps:

1. Find the value index. If given an index you can skip this step.
2. Compute the subtraction with the value or values below it.
3. Compute the subtraction with the value or values above it.

Note that you should only base your run on indices, not values.